# Customize part in TOC by titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I want to represent the `\part` in the TOC as on the figure below:

[image]

The problem is the `\part` could be represented so simple as other headers. As you see in the MWE below, the `\part` design has been created by same way as `\section`, but the color box in not displayed in the first case:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\contentsmargin{2.55em}

\titlecontents{part}[0pc]
{}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},]
\node [thick, draw=LavenderBlush4, fill=LavenderBlush1, rectangle, rounded corners] {\thecontentslabel};\end{tikzpicture}\quad}
{}
{}

\titlecontents{section}[0pc]
{}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},]
\node [thick, draw=LavenderBlush4, fill=LavenderBlush1, rectangle, rounded corners] {\thecontentslabel};\end{tikzpicture}\quad}
{}
{$\:$\titlerule[0.5pt]$\:$\small\thecontentspage}

\dottedcontents{subsection}[3.6em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}

\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[1.8pc]
{\small}{\thecontentslabel}
{}{\,---\,\thecontentspage}[\quad][]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A}
\section{AA}
\subsection{AAA}
\subsubsection{AAAA}
\subsubsection{AAAB}
\subsection{AAB}
\subsection{AAC}
\subsection{AAD}
\subsubsection{AADA}
\subsubsection{AADB}
\subsubsection{AADC}
\subsubsection{AADD}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, citing the `titlesec` manual

> Standard parts write the toc entry number in a non standard way. You may change that with `newparttoc` so that `titletoc` or a similar package can manipulate the entry. (That works only if `\part` has been redeﬁned.)

This means that you have to load the `titlesec` package with the option `newparttoc`

```
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
```

and redefine `\part` in a way to reproduce the standard `article` class behavior:

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Large\bfseries}
{\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}
{0mm}
{\huge\bfseries}
```

After doing that, your `tikzpicture` magically appears...

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Large\bfseries}
{\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}
{0mm}
{\huge\bfseries}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\contentsmargin{2.55em}

\titlecontents{part}[0pc]
{}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},]
\node [thick, draw=LavenderBlush4, fill=LavenderBlush1, rectangle, rounded corners] {\thecontentslabel};\end{tikzpicture}\quad}
{}
{}

\titlecontents{section}[0pc]
{}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)},]
\node [thick, draw=LavenderBlush4, fill=LavenderBlush1, rectangle, rounded corners] {\thecontentslabel};\end{tikzpicture}\quad}
{}
{$\:$\titlerule[0.5pt]$\:$\small\thecontentspage}

\dottedcontents{subsection}[3.6em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}

\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[1.8pc]
{\small}{\thecontentslabel}
{}{\,---\,\thecontentspage}[\quad][]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A}
\section{AA}
\subsection{AAA}
\subsubsection{AAAA}
\subsubsection{AAAB}
\subsection{AAB}
\subsection{AAC}
\subsection{AAD}
\subsubsection{AADA}
\subsubsection{AADB}
\subsubsection{AADC}
\subsubsection{AADD}

\end{document}
```