# How to add a subtitle to toc's title ("Contents")

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am trying to add a subtitle to toc's title.

Here is what  I have  done so far :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{supertabular}


% **************************
% Change toc's title ("Contents")
% **************************

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\begin{center}
    \fontsize{25}{12}\selectfont My new title
\end{center}
}


% **************************
% Two column's toc :
% **************************

\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

I have tried doing this :

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\begin{center}
    \fontsize{25}{12}\selectfont My new title \\ My subtitle
\end{center}
}
```

But my toc won't generate after that.

Thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package, you can put the `\contentsname` in a `\parbox{\linewidth}{}`, and then horizontally center with `\centerline{}` and break lines with `~\\` ([why the `~`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4692/170958)):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% Uncomment the two lines below if you want a two-column ToC
%\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
%\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{%
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
\centerline{Nice ToC}~\\[-1em]%
\centerline{\Large Some Subtitle}%
}}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \section{Some Section}\section{Some Other Section}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

Now, what exactly's going on behind the scenes here, I don't know. But hopefully this still helps.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your help. But it seems that your solution doesn't work with a two-columns toc.

Comment: @Guliup it does if you use package `multitoc` (see edited answer, inspired by [this blogpost](https://texblog.org/2013/08/14/tidy-and-compact-table-of-contents-with-multitoc/)). I hope that works for you

Comment: @Guliup I suspect this question is also related to [this other question of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537109/formatting-complex-table-of-contents); see my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539099/170958) there for more details.